# MVC C# Controller in App Service Azure only return view if it is included in .csproj

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a controller in MVC that only return a view (a .cshtml file resulting of the compilation of one angular application), This is the code:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     return View("~/frontend/dist/angular-project/index.cshtml");
}
```

It only works if the index.cshtml file in that path is included in .csproj. If not, the service return a 500 error code because it can not find the view (but it exists when i look for it in the server file explorer).

This is where file is included in .csproj, if i remove this line it does not work:

```
<ItemGroup>
...
     <Content Include="frontend\dist\angular-project\index.cshtml" />
...
</ItemGroup>
```

This file is the result of an angular app build, so it is no need the file to exists before the entire app is deployed in the continuous integration (where the file is generated as a result of the angular build). In my local machine it works, even with the file not included in .csproj, but when I deployed the app it only works when file is included in .csproj

Is there any way to get the controller to work and return the view correctly without having to include the file in the .csproj? (which implies having to compile the angular application locally in order to add it and is not really necessary)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your .csproj reference packages once.

Comment: Hi @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, i edited my post including the reference of the file in my csproj file

Comment: Add the default documents in the azure portal and check once

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I added index.cshtml in the default documents in the app service configuration but still not working. Only works the files which are included in csproj

Comment: Also add path mappings  also.Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71583364/16630207)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT Thanks for the answer, but i can not change the path mapping because in this project there is another pages, so the mapping is correct. By the way, I do not understand why in other angular projects in the same project in which the index.cshtml is included the application works and their controller returns the view index.cshtml correctly, but when it is removed from the csproj the view is not found. Is the only difference between files